# SQLAlchemy object with Null values pre-populating FlaskForm FloatField with string 'None'

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have optional FloatFields set up like this:

```
class TestForm(FlaskForm):
    data = FloatField('Test Field', validators=[Optional()])
```

This allow the user to leave the field blank. But when they go to edit the entry any Null values in the SQLAlchemy object are pre-populated with the string 'None'. I pre-populate the form like this:

```
class Entry(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.Float)

test_entry = Entry.query.filter_by(id=entry).first()
form = TestForm(obj=test_entry)
return render_template('test.html', form=form)
```

The problem is that FloatField will not accept a string. With 'None' being a string when the user tries to resubmit the edited entry they get a warning that all the FloatFields in the form with 'None' pre-populated are incorrect. But if they were pre-populated as a blank the user could re-submit without needing to delete the word 'None'.

Comment: What does your `Entry` model look like?

Comment: Edited my post above

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution but I used a workaround

```
if test_entry.data is None:
    form = TestForm(data='')
```